# Is any thing wrong in my code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Only last image is displaying why? in Log my array list of `Image` are displaying

```
-(void)BanerSlideshow{

    baner_scrool.delegate = self;
    baner_scrool.scrollEnabled = YES;
    baner_scrool.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

     NSLog(@"howmany %lu",(unsigned long)[bannerimages_list count]);


    for (int i = 0; i < [bannerimages_list count]; i++)
    {
        [baner_image sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[bannerimages_list objectAtIndex:i]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderm.png"]];

        NSLog(@"rrr value %@", [bannerimages_list objectAtIndex:i]);

    }

    [baner_scrool setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320 * [bannerimages_list count], baner_scrool.frame.size.height)];
    [baner_scrool setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.baner_scrool addSubview:baner_image];
}
```

Comment: Wht you are trying to do?

Comment: Whr is the baner_image initialized?

Comment: Add `baner_image` inside the for loop. Set the initial image = nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this;

```
-(void)BanerSlideshow{
    baner_scrool.delegate = self;
    baner_scrool.scrollEnabled = YES;
    baner_scrool.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


NSLog(@"howmany %lu",(unsigned long)[bannerimages_list count]);


for (int i = 0; i < [bannerimages_list count]; i++)
{
    UIImageView* baner_imageV2 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [baner_imageV2 sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[bannerimages_list objectAtIndex:i]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderm.png"]];
    baner_imageV2.frame = CGRectMake(i * 320, 0, 320, 320);
    [self.baner_scrool addSubview:baner_imageV2];

    NSLog(@"rrr value %@", [bannerimages_list objectAtIndex:i]);

}

[baner_scrool setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320 * [bannerimages_list count], baner_scrool.frame.size.height)];
[baner_scrool setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working fine and how can i add timer for auto scroll for each image with 10 sec delay

Comment: @NDoc your code is correct and same as mine but a little difference is that you are not setting frame of UIImageView in the loop.

Comment: @sai you may create a new question for the auto scrolling but you may also try https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kiimagepager

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)BanerSlideshow{
    baner_scrool.delegate = self;
    baner_scrool.scrollEnabled = YES;
    baner_scrool.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


NSLog(@"howmany %lu",(unsigned long)[bannerimages_list count]);


for (int i = 0; i < [bannerimages_list count]; i++)
{
    UIImageView* images = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [images sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[bannerimages_list objectAtIndex:i]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderm.png"]];
    images.frame = CGRectMake(i * self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 320);
    [self.baner_scrool addSubview:images];

    NSLog(@"rrr value %@", [bannerimages_list objectAtIndex:i]);

}

[baner_scrool setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * [bannerimages_list count], baner_scrool.frame.size.height)];
[baner_scrool setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

}
```

Comment: Pls try dynamically both ipad and iphone